# How to creat byte array dynamically with different name and different size?

Tags: java, android

I am stuck in this little complex situation. I am writing part of android application, where I am reading an Mp3 file into multiple byte arrays. Problem is this number of byte arrays will be decided by a text file from USB and as well as the size of each byte array. 
Please suggest me a way out.

Below is my code where i am reading the Mp3 file

```
cxt = ControlUnit.getAppContext();
   try {

       File file = new File("/mnt/media/USBDISK1/IFrame_00.bin");

       input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));


          //input = cxt.getAssets().open("Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3");
          Log.i("TvPlayerFunctionalTestApp", "mp3 file Read from Assests");
   } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          Log.i("TvPlayerFunctionalTestApp", "Error in Opening mp3 File");
          e.printStackTrace();
   }

   try {
          size = input.available();
          Log.i("TvPlayerFunctionalTestApp", "Size of Bin File: "+size);
   } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
   }

try {
          buffer = new byte[AClipTextFileHandler.BufferSize.get(0)];
          input.read(buffer);
   //     input.read(buffer, offset, length);
          Log.i("TvPlayerFunctionalTestApp", "buffer: "+ Arrays.toString(buffer));
          buffer1 = new byte[AClipTextFileHandler.BufferSize.get(1)];
          input.read(buffer1);
          Log.i("TvPlayerFunctionalTestApp", "buffer: "+ Arrays.toString(buffer1));
          StringBuffer stringBuff = new StringBuffer();

       for (byte b:buffer)
       {
          stringBuff.append(String.format("%x", b));
       }
       Log.i("TvPlayerFunctionalTestApp","buffer: "+stringBuff) ;
       for (byte b:buffer1)
       {
           stringBuff.append(String.format("%x", b));
       }

   } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
          Log.i("TvPlayerFunctionalTestApp", "Error in Read");
   }
try {
          input.close();
          Log.i("TvPlayerFunctionalTestApp", "File closed");
   } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

I am unable to understand how `List<Byte> arrays = new ArrayList<Byte>()` can help me.

Comment: If you want to have a List of byte arrays, use instead `List<byte[]> arrays = new ArrayList<byte>()`. `byte[]` is an array of bytes, but it is not a primitive and can be used as such in generics.

Comment: int TotalBuffer = AClipTextFileHandler.BufferID.get(0);
           while (TotalBuffer !=0){
             bufferData[i]= new byte[AClipTextFileHandler.BufferSize.get(j)];
             input.read(bufferData[i]);
             i++;
             j++;
             TotalBuffer--;

Answer (score 0):

How about the below attempt. 
Total Buffer will be taken from the text file which i am reading.

```
                  int TotalBuffer = AClipTextFileHandler.BufferID.get(0);

                  while (TotalBuffer !=0){

                  bufferData[i]= new byte[AClipTextFileHandler.BufferSize.get(j)];
                  input.read(bufferData[i]);
                  i++;
                  j++;
                  TotalBuffer--;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer .

```
                      while (TotalBuffer !=0){
                      buffer= new byte[AClipTextFileHandler.BufferSize.get(j)];
                      input.read(buffer);
                      j++;
                      TotalBuffer--;
```

Where j is the size of my byte array which is taken from the text file. And TotalBuffer is the number of byte arrays to be created which is again taken from the text file.